# Dart - filter array by json value

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have this JSON response:

```
{
    "suggestions": [
        {
            "label": "United States, <b>New York</b>",
            "language": "en",
            "countryCode": "USA",
            "locationId": "NT_rNsDLtnazM.kjVC-K6YWOA",
            "address": {
                "country": "United States",
                "state": "<b>New York</b>"
            },
            "matchLevel": "state"
        },
        {
            "label": "United States, <b>New York</b>, <b>New York</b>, <b>New York</b>",
            "language": "en",
            "countryCode": "USA",
            "locationId": "NT_YpQcXqbaOb.I4m5EW8BHEC",
            "address": {
                "country": "United States",
                "state": "<b>New York</b>",
                "county": "<b>New York</b>",
                "city": "<b>New York</b>",
                "postalCode": "10007"
            },
            "matchLevel": "city"
        },
        {
            "label": "United States, <b>New York</b>, <b>New York</b>",
            "language": "en",
            "countryCode": "USA",
            "locationId": "NT_ABhedB4xGEL83YY5az47iD",
            "address": {
                "country": "United States",
                "state": "<b>New York</b>",
                "county": "<b>New York</b>"
            },
            "matchLevel": "county"
        },
        {
            "label": "United Kingdom, NE27 0, North Shields, <b>New York</b> Way",
            "language": "en",
            "countryCode": "GBR",
            "locationId": "NT_B24AwYSzW4TK04x9UiKMoD",
            "address": {
                "country": "United Kingdom",
                "state": "England",
                "county": "Tyne and Wear",
                "city": "North Shields",
                "district": "North Shields",
                "street": "<b>New York</b> Way",
                "postalCode": "NE27 0"
            },
            "matchLevel": "street"
        },
        {
            "label": "United States, <b>New York</b>, Buffalo, <b>New York</b> State Thruway",
            "language": "en",
            "countryCode": "USA",
            "locationId": "NT_-WyF-KGZ-pqF8zQV6NegHD",
            "address": {
                "country": "United States",
                "state": "<b>New York</b>",
                "county": "Erie",
                "city": "Buffalo",
                "district": "Grant Ferry",
                "street": "<b>New York</b> State Thruway",
                "postalCode": "14213"
            },
            "matchLevel": "street"
        }
    ]
}
```

And in code I would like to display only values which `matchLevel` type is `city`.

So far I've been trying this but it does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var data = json.decode(res.body);
      var rest = data["suggestions"] as List;
      var filteredList;
      rest.forEach((val) => filteredList.add(rest.where((val) => val["matchLevel"] == "city")));
      print(filteredList);

      this.list =
          filteredList.map<Suggestions>((json) => Suggestions.fromJson(json)).toList();
```

Tried also this:

Comment: check this for a sample example: https://dartpad.dev/ad23d7a149716a59dfcc371861136546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var data = json.decode(res.body);
      var rest = data["suggestions"] as List;
      var filteredList;
      rest.forEach((val) => filteredList.add(rest.where((val) => val["matchLevel"] == "city")));
      print(filteredList);
```

into this:

```
var data = json.decode(res.body);
      var rest = data["suggestions"] as List;
      var filteredList;
      filteredList = rest.where((val) => val["matchLevel"] == "city");
      print(filteredList);
```

From the [docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/Iterable/where.html):

> This method returns a view of the mapped elements. As long as the returned `Iterable` is not iterated over, the supplied function test will not be invoked. Iterating will not cache results, and thus iterating multiple times over the returned `Iterable` may invoke the supplied function test multiple times on the same element.

Therefore when you use `forEach()` and `where()` you will get the same result multiple times.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. My bad! It works. Thanks!

Comment: Why is it returning result object in brackets | i got this output : ({label: United States, <b>New York</b>, <b>New York</b>, <b>New York</b>, language: en, countryCode: USA, locationId: NT_YpQcXqbaOb.I4m5EW8BHEC, address: {country: United States, state: <b>New York</b>, county: <b>New York</b>, city: <b>New York</b>, postalCode: 10007}, matchLevel: city})